# how to use free cloud database with android app?

Tags: android, cloud

I am developing an Google maps android application in which I want to use database in cloud for saving usernames, passwords, GPS Locations etc.
Can any option to achieve this with free of cost ? 
If there are any examples, posts, or tutorials?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Now there are a lot of cloud providers , providing solutions like MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a Service). Some only give access to cloud database, some will do the user management for you, some let you place code around cloud database and there are facilities of access control, push notifications, analytics, integrated image and file hosting etc.

Here are some providers which have a "free-tier" (may change in future):

1. Firebase (Google) - https://firebase.google.com/
2. AWS Amplify (Amazon) - https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/
3. Azure Mobile (Microsoft) - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/app-service/mobile
4. MongoDB Mobile (MongoDB) - https://www.mongodb.com/use-cases/mobile
5. Back4app (Popular) - https://www.back4app.com/

**Open source solutions**, that you can self host:

1. Parse - http://parseplatform.org/
2. AppWrite - https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite
3. SupaBase - https://supabase.io/
4. Nakama - https://github.com/heroiclabs/nakama
5. Nhost - https://github.com/nhost/nhost
6. Loopback - https://loopback.io/

Comment: Thank you very very much for suggestion. I m cheeking this for my App.

Comment: in my android App i want that any user around the world when download and register my app then their information and GPS location want to save in the database and then he appear in Google Maps as a marker. He/She can be seen to all user who use that app in same time ...............now i think you will understand what i want to achieve...........  can you please suggest me any example or tutorial for this kind of situations ...thank you for your response....

Comment: i have register in Bitnami and AWS also but now i dont understand how to use with my android app.........   http://bitnami.org/cloud

Comment: @alex_android_dev  Google already provides **Google Places API** for this. users can use their Google account, check-in at a place from any where. Your app will be able to use all that ready made data if user allows your app to use their Google account.    Link : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: Firebase ok for me..

Comment: Even I am also beginning with android .I am creating a login and registration example in android.With Sql lite I achieved it .But it will be in my local device.Does fire base or any open source free cloud db which I can use to store registration and login details which  is available in market.Does this exposes any uri which I can use to consume or to pass data for insertion.Any helpful links would be good.TIA.Basically if I insert data from android using registration form it should go and  insert into cloud db.So that if some queries queries cloud db same result should be got.

Answer (score 2):

As Wingman said, Google App Engine is a great solution for your scenario.

You can get some information about GAE+Android here:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android

And from this Google IO 2012 session:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4

Comment: Thank you very very much for suggestion. I m cheeking this for my App.

Comment: Hello Aerilys, Thanks to suggest me, but i have read that it is for web web application how can i use Google App Engine for my Android App. ?       waiting for your replay........

Comment: Actually you have to expose your datastore access (on App Engine) through web services, which can be consumed by your Android app

Comment: thank you Aerilys, but i m new for android and my actual doubt is that we are use web service to retrieve our data right ? but here i want to first send data to the database server and then retrieve..can you please suggest me any example or tutorial for this kind of situations ...thank you for response....

Comment: The Google IO session link is provided up there can help you. And this session too: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U. You can also look at the code generated by Eclipse when you create a project "“App Engine Connected Android Project"

Comment: in my android App i want that any user around the world when download and register my app then their information and GPS location want to save in the database and then he appear in Google Maps as a marker. He/She can be seen to all user who use that app in same time ...............now i think you will understand what i want to achieve........... can you please suggest me any example or tutorial for this kind of situations ...thank you for your response....