# Sharing same SQLite DB for two android apps

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to maintain single sqlite DB for two applications. I have seen other links and this was helpful [Share SQLite database between 2 android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps)

But still when I declare the shared user ID and shared context, I could not achieve it.

In my first app- SQLite is created with few tables. 
In my second app=- I would to create tables in the same DB which I created in first app

And also in few posts, I read that this can be achieved through remote Database.

Please can some one suggest me good tutorial where I can have some idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Share the code you've tried using, the errors you encountered etc.

Comment: you also can use content provider to share data with other apps

Comment: Both apps need to be signed by the same key in addition to the same `sharedUserId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend what you've asked about - which is using a remote database.

Check out this: [how to use free cloud database with android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104756/how-to-use-free-cloud-database-with-android-app)

Look into a hosted database in the cloud. Quite a few of them will let you get started for free. I know IrisCouch lets you get going for free and it's very easy. http://www.iriscouch.com/ The nice thing about CouchDB is you can do all your work via HTTP - which isn't too hard from an Android device.