# How can I put my Android database onto some "central server"?

Tags: android, webserver, hosting, android-sqlite

I'm actually new in the software development and wants detailed guidance here. I just have developed an android app with **SQLite-Database**

Now When I completed this app, the size of data of the database became very large. So now I want to put this data onto some **central server**

> **What should I do for it??**

And

> **Is there any other feasible solution for it which would be better financially and functionally (means better performance)??**
>
> **My SQLite database code will be changed or not???**

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104756/how-to-use-free-cloud-database-with-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data on the server, but don't access it directly. Instead, write a webservice which you can query from your app, and which will return the necessary results to you.

It will be both easier to maintain and a more secure way of accessing your data than attempting a raw app to database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine and use Google Cloud Messaging to send a receive data from the cloud... Take a look here:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae