# How I can create backups for my notes in Android app by using Gmail account or a server or by extract a file?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an Android app, and it's for writing and saves notes in SQLite database. I need to make backups for the notes by using Gmail account (If the user sign in with his email in the app, the app automatically syncs and gets the notes). Or by saving the notes on a server (If the user press the Sync button, the app automatically gets the notes (But here, how the app or the server knows if the user is the correct user, and gets his the correct notes?!)). Or by extract a file into any directory, and the file contains the notes, if the user press Restore button in the app, the app will start looking for the file in all directories and gets the notes.

I searched about that, but I have no idea how I can start!

Can anyone explain the whole idea about that?! (If anyone can bring source codes or tutorials for that, it will be a good explanation! :D).

- Note: I am a beginner, so please try to make your answers more simple. Thanks a lot!
- Here is my app on Google Play Store: [My Notes app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes)

Comment: Your app is already doing those Gmail login? and fetches the notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use android's BackupAgentHelper.

Here is sample:
Add in your manifest:

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"...>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="key_from_google_api" />
....
</application>
```

Create one class as:

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    private String KEY = "key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        addHelper(KEY, new FileBackupHelper(this, DATABASE_NAME));
    }

    @Override
    public File getFilesDir(){
        File path = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return path.getParentFile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
    }
}
```

You are ready to go!!!

Comment: Is this class to save and restore only settings?! or the whole data, like: notes, settings, etc...?!

Comment: It will backup and restore your sql database.

Comment: If you want to do for shared Preferences, you can do similar way.

Comment: Note that, the app has many users, how the app knows the correct notes for the correct user?! And where the backups will placed?! Also, if the user change his phone, how can he restore his notes?!

Comment: Any numbers of users are there, but you have db file as 1 and when db restore, you can filter data as you were doing without backup status.

Comment: No need to implement the methods that you are wrote it above?! Just copy and paste?! Another thing, when the app will make the backups and when it will restore them?! Sorry about my Q's, you know, I am a beginner. :(

Comment: It will be manage by Android itself, generally it will do backup at time interval and in ideal state of mobile. For testing it during development, you can do like:     
Backup:
adb shell bmgr backup com.vasakinnar.test

You can ensure scheduled backup run :
adb shell bmgr run

And you can restore your backup by calling bmgr restore feaure :
adb shell bmgr restore com.vasakinnar.test

Comment: Ok, I made an API Key for my app. Also, I copied and pasted your code inside my project. No need to add anything to the code?! Just compile and run and test my app, and after that update it on Google Play Store?!

Comment: Please can you answer to my question?! This is the last question from me.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do anything except above, but for testing, do above steps I mentioned before release on play store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/)** to connect your mobile app to Google Cloud.

Check this out:
[Saving Android application data in Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938489/saving-android-application-data-in-google-cloud)