# android - store information in database

Tags: android, database

I want to store texts from android devices into a database. I'd like to know if it's possible with a webserver and webspace, so I don't need to run a server myself? Are there any tutorials to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**About cloud providers** :  go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104862/3872374) which is already well defined .

**About tutorial** : There are many solution provided on google but I would recommend you to go the link for quality solution by google [google codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/)

I would also recommend you to go through this simple tutorial at which is based you asked [google codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-create-cloud-sql-db/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) . And there are also many other good tutorials provided, simply browse through the category .

hope it helps ..

Comment: I guess using google or other external cloud services isn't for free, is it?

Comment: And is there a tutorial especially for android usage?

Comment: Yes , google codelabs is especially for android usage . did you check the link ? .